Prevent overwriting PostGIS layers when synchronizing with QGIS Offline Editing plugin
Is there any mechanism in QGIS (3.38.x) that prevents overwriting PostGIS layers when synchronizing offline GPKG files with the corresponding remote PostgreSQL datasources?
Are "read-only" layers automatically excluded from the synchronization process?
If we define some layers as "read-only", are changes in PostGIS datasources automatically transferred to the "read-only" GPKG layer?
Is the "Offline Editing" plugin the right tool for one way synchronization from PostGIS => GPKG?

As I have just discovered in a test project, "read-only" layers are perfectly synchronized. But after synchronization the connection to the "remote datasource" is lost. Is this an intended behavior?

The connection loss is in QGIS 3.38.1. In QGIS 3.36.2 everything is fine. Seems to be a bug.
